# How to get raw request header in token validation stage of IdentityServer4 (asp.net core)?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I need to read the IP address from request header in `ResourcePasswordValidator` when people login. But I could not find it in `ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext`. The document I followed: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resource_owner.html

PS: `LocalApiAuthentication` is used, and I'm new to IdentityServer4 framework. Thanks.

Codes in Startup.cs:

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(ApiConfig.GetApis())
                .AddInMemoryClients(ApiConfig.GetClients())
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(ApiConfig.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddResourceOwnerValidator<ResourcePasswordValidator>()
                .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
            
            services.AddLocalApiAuthentication();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.PolicyName, policy =>
                {
                    policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.AuthenticationScheme);
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                });
            });
        }

       
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside OWIN Startup.cs, add the password validator middleware to your Identity configuration:

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
        {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
            
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
            .AddRoleStore<ApplicationRoleStore>()
            .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
            .AddRoleManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
            .AddPasswordValidator<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>() //right here                
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: I'm using IdentityServer4 instead of owin, and I have already add a similar stuff:
`.AddResourceOwnerValidator<ResourcePasswordValidator>() `